# Craft error on NFS filesystem

Tags: craft2, hosting

I have a Craft 2 install that's been working fine until recently when the admin page is giving an error:

file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream

The front end is fine.

It seems (according to https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html) that NFS filesystems do not like Exclusive Locks, and the host uses NFS (the webserver the site is on connects to a backend filer via NFS to read the actual webfiles)

so I have tried changing

/config/general.php

so that useFileLock is set to 'false' but this hasn't changed anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Make sure you're using `false` the boolean and not `'false'` the string.
2. After you change `useFileLocks` to `false`, clear the `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder as I believe that setting is cached for whatever the [cacheDuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#cacheduration) config setting is set to.